# Can anyone help explaining this?

Tags: apache-flex, byte

i want to write audiodata in a flv file.

I found the structure of video tag in flv to be

```
Name  Expression  Description  
codecID  (byte & 0x0f) » 0  2: Sorensen H.263, 3: Screen video, 4: On2 VP6, 5: On2 VP6 Alpha, 6: ScreenVideo 2  
frameType  (byte & 0xf0) » 4  1: keyframe, 2: inter frame, 3: disposable inter frame
```

And in the flex code it's written like this

```
// VIDEODATA 'header'
    v.writeByte(0x13); // frametype (1) + codecid (3)
```

so what does it mean? Are they describing the frametype and codecid in the hexadecimal value 0X13?

For Audio

```
soundType  (byte & 0x01) » 0  0: mono, 1: stereo  
soundSize  (byte & 0x02) » 1  0: 8-bit, 1: 16-bit  
soundRate  (byte & 0x0C) » 2  0: 5.5 kHz, 1: 11 kHz, 2: 22 kHz, 3: 44 kHz  
soundFormat  (byte & 0xf0) » 4  0: Uncompressed, 1: ADPCM, 2: MP3, 5: Nellymoser 8kHz mono, 6: Nellymoser, 11: Speex
```

Comment: What is this exactly 0xAF? Could you elaborate as to give some hints on what exactly you want to do and what it has to do with byte manipulation?

Comment: It looks like your Sound Format list is incomplete. Judging by the comments in the code you provided, a 10 Sound Format might be AAC.

Comment: btw, @above doesn't do anything... you need to use the username, or at least the first part of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. `(byte & 0x0f) >> 0` means that codecID is contained in the lower four bits of `byte` (hex f = binary 1111). Similarly, `(byte & 0xf0) >> 4` says that frameType is stored in the upper four bits of `byte`. So the 1 in 0x13 is the frame type (keyframe), and the 3 is the codecID (Screen video).

Comment: @jswolf- If i want to specify stereo,16bit ,44khz and speex.
then is it the correct format
a.writebyte(0x013B) is correct?

Comment: @karthick, no, Audio is still one byte (two hexadecimal digits). if the byte is the 8 binary digits `abcdefgh`, then `h` is the soundType, `g` is the soundSize, `ef` is the soundRate, and `abcd` is the soundFormat. To create your byte, you can reverse the shifting (shifting is done with the `>>` operator) you show above. So: `byte = (soundByte<<0) + (soundSize<<1) + (soundRate<<2) + (soundFormat<<4)`

Comment: @jswolf: I calculated and it came to 0xB9.

Comment: @karthick, hex 9 = binary 1001, so your `soundType` is 1 (stereo), `soundSize` is 0 (8-bit), and `soundRate` is binary 10 = decimal 2 (22kHz). hex B = decimal 11, so your soundFormat is Speex, so that's good.